# Customizing specifically the Sign Up page in Azure AD B2C

Tags: html, azure, azure-ad-b2c

Azure AD B2C is a pretty cool feature that provides signup/signin functionality. I can't figure out how to customize the sign up page in the custom user flows section specifically though. Using this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-ui-customization I customized the login page by styling what Azure injects into the div of id `api`. On that default page, it also has a `don't have an account? Sign up 'here'`. I don't see a place to put in a resource for the sign up page though. Does anyone know how to customize the sign up page specifically, in addition to how I've customized the login?

By the way, I'm using Netlify to host the login page. I am not using blob storage that they use in the link I referenced. Any help would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Sign up` page is another individual page, if you want to custom it, you can find its `ContentDefinitions` by id:`api.localaccountsignup` just as below:

[image]

You can specify your custom sign up page URL at `LoadUri` tag.

if you are using B2C custom policy, just follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-ui-customization#4-modify-the-extensions-file) to do that: , if you are just using B2C Built-in user flows, you can specify your custom sign up URL here:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Stanley! Where do I add that within the azure portal? And is the sign up page the same format in that I create the markup and then add a div with id of api and it works the same way? Thank you again

Comment: Oh dang, can't believe I missed that spot in the portal. I got it working. Thank you very much!